# How do I read the text in the notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am trying to read the text in the notification, so I can assign labels values based on what the notification says. And I also need help on opening a certain view controller when the notification is clicked. How would I do this? I am very new to dealing with notifications, so any help is appreciated.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let notificationDictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
            self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notificationDictionary)
            print("text: \(notificationDictionary)")
        }
    }

    return true
}

 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text of the notification with

```
userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]
```

didReceiveRemoteNotification is called

- when the notif is received if the app is in the foreground
- when the notif is clicked if the app was in the background

To distinguish between these cases :

```
if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active { }
```

Note that there is another case you need to handle: the notif is clicked while the app is closed. In this case, didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called, but the notif will be accessible in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launch options :

```
launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
```

Comment: So how will I be able to get the text of the notification? I understand the difference between the active and inactive state, but I am still confused on how to get the actual text of the notification, and redirection to a certain view controller.

Comment: The text of the notif is userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]

Comment: For the redirection, you need to handle it in 2 places : in didReceiveRemoteNotification when the app is not in the active state, and in didReceiveRemoteNotification when the launchoptions dictionnary contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey

Comment: How would I capture only part of the text in the notification?